# I'm attempting to import a picture into my projecy but does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, image, bufferedimage

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public class spriteStore {
public static BufferedImage playerStanding;

public void getImage()
{
    try
    {
        playerStanding = ImageIO.read(new File("Cobalt\\pictures\\playerStanding1.png"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Picture not found");}
}
}
```

I am trying to read an image to save as a BufferedImage object, but when i run the main code,

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Cobalt {
public Boolean movingLeft, movingRight, firstJump, secondJump;
public int jump = 0;
public Dimension screenSize;
public JFrame frame;
public JPanel panel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run(){
            new Cobalt();
        }
    });

}
public Cobalt()
{
    frame = new JFrame("COBALT");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setSize(500,500); //width and height
    panel = new MyPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
}
class MyPanel extends JPanel
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paint(g);
        g2D.drawImage(spriteStore.playerStanding, 100, 100, null);
    }
}
}
```

and the image will not show up. I'm using eclipse, and am relatively a noob, so please inform me of my error.

Comment: try to search how to use bufferedImage first in this stack overflow..

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do custom painting to show an image.

You can use a JLabel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have in your project a structure like this:

```
Cobalt
|
\---src
    |   Cobalt.java
    |               
    \---pictures
            playerStanding1.png
```

Try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().
            getResource("pictures/playerStanding1.png");

    BufferedImage playerStanding = ImageIO.read(url);

    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(playerStanding));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to create the jlabel

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif",
                             "a pretty but meaningless splat"); 
JLabel thumb = new JLabel();
thumb.setIcon(icon);
```

And load the image like this

```
/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                       String description) {
java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
if (imgURL != null) {
    return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
} else {
    //System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
    return null;
}
}
```

And if you want it from a url

```
URL PicURL = new URL("http://...");
ImageIcon imgThisImg = new ImageIcon(PicURL));
jLabel2.setIcon(imgThisImg);
```

Comment: -1, this answer was given earlier with the actual link to the tutorial provided. No need for a duplicate answer. You just copied the code from the tutorial. It is better for the OP to read the tutorial to understand what it going on. The tutorial provides additional explanations.

Comment: @camickr actually i wrote my answer before you gave the link, then i updated adding the code from the tutorial and then i realise that you provided the same resource i was watching.